# How to add and delete a user to another group using the Group module?

Tags: 7, rules

I am using Drupal 7 and the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. I would like to create  reaction rule or some code which automatically signs the user up to group 'blue', when they sign up to group 'red'.

I wouldn't mind using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or hard coding it. The only thing is that if the user leaves the first group, I want to be able to cancel their membership in the second group too.

What would be the easiest way? I have of course tried Rules without success and I cannot find a simple way to hard code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. When using the group module, there are methods which work well. I used a hook_group_membership_insert($group_membership):

```
function [my_module]_group_membership_insert($group_membership) {

   $grouptest = group_load($group_membership->gid);
   $grouptest->addMember($group_membership->uid);
}
```

The same exists for deleting a member, just use the following function:

```
$grouptest->removeMember($uid);
```

Comment: Hi "same firstname" ... Please enhance your answer to explain your code. E.g. what your "first group" is in it, and what your "second group is". Also, let me know if you're interested in an extra answer to illustrates "How to add a user to another group" (as in your title). Note: your 2nd parg of your question body is really like a different question I think, no?

Comment: Hi Pierre :) I would love it if you knew how to do it via Rules for people who are less happy with coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Add user to another group

To answer 1 of your questions (= "*How to add a user to another group?*"): it is indeed possible to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module has all sorts of out-of-the-box integrations with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)).

To do so, you can use a variation of what's explained in [comment # 5](https://www.drupal.org/node/2581499#comment-10574610) of the issue about "[Bulk adding users to a group](https://www.drupal.org/node/2581499)". Here is a rule (in Rules export format) that should do the job:

```
{ "rules_create_additional_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create additional group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "group" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "group" ],
    "ON" : { "group_membership_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "group-membership:group:gid" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "group_membership" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "created_group_mbrship" : "Created group mbrship" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "created-group-mbrship:group" ], "value" : "2" } },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "created-group-mbrship:user" ],
          "value" : [ "site:current-user" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "created-group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "active" } },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "created-group-mbrship" ], "immediate" : "1" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about this rule:

- Rules Event: After saving a new group membership.
- Rules Conditions: Check that the group for the new membership is `1` (adapt this to fit your "1st group").
- Rules Actions:

  - Create a new entity (Entity type = Group membership).
  - Set a data value for `group` (= `2`, adapt this to fit your "2nd group").
  - Set a data value for `user` (= `[site:current-user]`).
  - Set a data value for `status` (= `Active`, assuming that's the status you want).
  - Save the entity (make sure to use `Force saving immediately`).

If you have the Rules UI (and the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module) enabled, you should be able to just import the above rule in your own site (after you eventually edited the group IDs `1` and `2` to fit your own needs).

## Remove user from another group

Your 2nd question (= "*... if the user leaves the first group, I want to be able to cancel their membership in the second group too ...*") is really a different question. The major challenge to answer it is that when something happens to the 1st group, you want something to happen in the 2nd group.

Here is a (rather basic) Rules Component that you could use to change such membership to status "blocked":

```
{ "rules_remove_a_single_group_membership" : {
    "LABEL" : "Remove a single group membership",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "group_mbrship" : { "label" : "Group membership", "type" : "group_membership" },
      "user" : { "label" : "User", "type" : "user" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:group:gid" ], "value" : "2" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "group-mbrship:status" ], "value" : "blocked" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note the Rules Condition that checks that the group for the membership to be blocked is `2` (adapt this to fit your "2nd group").

The only thing left is to have this Rules Component triggered via a Rules Action of another (extra) rule that is triggered when a user leaves the 1st Group. If you wonder how to do that, and to avoid my answer gets marked as *access only for +15K users*, please use [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link.